# Django pass object (self) from page to views.py

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a function in views.py - I know it works

I want to send the current object from a page to the views.py as a parameter. How do I do this?

this is the current view

```
def sourceMedia(request, stream_id):
    stream = get_object_or_404(Stream, pk=stream_id)

    return render(request, 'livestream/sourceMedia.html', {'specificMedia': stream})
```

now from this page I want to request a function to be executed in views. Currently I'm using an ajax call, but how do I send the object and what is the object?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you know what the object is?

Comment: you can send data back to django either through the URL (via regex pattern or URL parameters), via HTTP headers, or POST. Can you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a model instance/object itself as you have it on the backend from the template/frontend to a view.

You can send an id (as you already do) to identify it on the backend, a serialized version of it (which wouldn't make much sense though) or save it in the session to retrieve it in another request/response pair.